# Highcharts area fill top

Tags: highcharts

I searched highcharts documentation and several search engines to find a solution for my problem, but didn't find any suitable solution.

I want to create a chart with area series that fills up its fillColor to the top of the chart. It would lool like if you reverse the depending yAxes, but without reversing the values. 
I don't want to use arearange series type because in raw data table and exports I don't wand to show "low" and "high" value. I just want to use y value.

Is there a way to do it in a simple way. Maybe there is an option in highcharts which I overlooked.

Comment: it is entirely unclear what you're asking for. Please review this for better results: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can add `rect` which will have dimensions of whole plot area, and add the animation on it. In order to draw the element, just need to call `Chart.renderer.rect()` on `chart.events.load` handler. Whole process would look like below:

Create new element on `load` event, set its color and opacity attributes equal to the default ones, and then add animation:

```
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
        load() {
            var rect = this.renderer.rect(this.plotLeft, this.plotTop, 0, this.plotHeight)
              .attr({
                  fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                  opacity: 0.8
              })
              .add()
            rect.animate({
                width: this.plotWidth
            }, {
                duration: 1000
            })
        }
    }
},
```

Then set the series `fillColor` equal to white (or the other color of the plot area):

```
series: [{
        name: 'USA',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        data: [
            ... some data ...
        ]
}]
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/up8f5x34/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.fillColor